# Looking for software to combine articles into ebook

Tags: epub, software

I'm looking for a way to combine articles from the Internet into an ebook that I can then read on my ebook reader. I have tried:

(1) using the Export Pocket to EPub Chrome extension, but all it did was just take me to the extension's homepage.

(2) using Instapaper and Pocket as custom news sources with Calibre but the ebooks Calibre created were empty.

(3) using the EpubPress Chrome extension, which with about 10 article got stuck in the 'Fetching Images' stage and then did nothing.

Are there any other specific approaches I can try? Thank you.

Comment: you can just save the page (with all content) and convert that to the epub format (iirc calibre can do so, it is also not that difficult to write a python program that does so).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Blog to book](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/1203/convert-blog-to-book)

Comment: Caveat: not all EPUB readers support all media even if your tool puts all the media into the EPUB. Most readers support the JPG and PNG formats but maybe not SVG, which is part of the EPUB3 spec. And some video formats may not be supported by the reader. To test your reader go here: http://www.epubtest.org/. There is an EPUB file you can download to test your reader and each test gives you a PASS or FAIL result. [Click here for the EPUB files to run testing](http://www.epubtest.org/testsuite/).

Answer (score 2):

Actually with instapaper (if you're logged in) You can visit either:

- https://instapaper.com/mobi
- https://instapaper.com/epub

to download the latest 20 articles.

Then there is the normal download option in the drop down menu (under your user name).

Answer (score 1):

Some better chrome extension is [Website to PDF](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/website-to-pdf/gkdcbpbinmenbpbnmihiddmmilgbahhe?hl=en)

One solution for creation of PDF directly in Chrome browser. All tabs in window are merged in one page and after that with internal for browser print functionality they can be saved in PDF.

One extension have to be added in Chrome - [Merge all tabs for print or save](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/merge-all-tabs-for-print/olcjnbnibcfbehmfnkomljcgelbggjkf?utm_source=stackexchange)

Comment: This seems interesting. Are there similar extensions for other browsers?

Answer (score 0):

Two fast solutions:

1. Download individual articles into Evernote app or Offline Browser app. Note: free versions of Evernote only works with Internet access.
2. A simple cut and paste into MS Word and save as PDF works if you're looking for something fast.